# SQL Select to obtain more column with different conditions

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

Hello I cannot manage to create a query that shows different columns related to a different WHERE condition. Here my use case:
The Database reports TEST measurements performed on UNITS tested on several MACHINES.

I need to have a report for each DISTINCT TEST with The AVERAGE values of TEST values for EACH UNIT.
(I can hardcode the MACHINE number so I can simplify the query).

- TEST A: Average Measure for unit 1, Average Measure for unit 2, Average Meas for unit N
- TEST B: Average Measure for unit 1, Average Measure for unit 2, Average Meas for unit N
- TEST C: Average Measure for unit 1, Average Measure for unit 2, Average Meas for unit N
- ...

[image: Here how the output should be]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select testname,
       avg(case when unit = 11 then measure end) as unit_11,
       avg(case when unit = 22 then measure end) as unit_22,
       avg(case when unit = 33 then measure end) as unit_33,
       avg(case when unit = 44 then measure end) as unit_44
from t
group by testname;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I needed :)